# fedex serviceavailabilityrequest is failing

Tags: php, fedex

I am trying to integrate the fedex serviceavailabilty to return estimated delivery times based on the service type used.

I am using xml via http post using curl, but it is giving me an error.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="en">Fault</faultstring>
    <detail>
       <cause>Transient</cause>
       <code>unknownCode</code>
       <desc>java.lang.NullPointerException</desc>
</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault
```

My code is as follows:

```
$request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
    <ns:ServiceAvailabilityRequest xmlns:ns=\"http://fedex.com/ws/vacs/v4\">
        <ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ns:UserCredential>
                <ns:Key>{$this->apikey}</ns:Key>
                <ns:Password>{$this->password}</ns:Password>
            </ns:UserCredential>
        </ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <ns:ClientDetail>
            <ns:AccountNumber>{$this->account}</ns:AccountNumber>
            <ns:MeterNumber>{$this->meter}</ns:MeterNumber>
        </ns:ClientDetail>
        <ns:TransactionDetail>
            <ns:CustomerTransactionId>ServiceAvailabilityRequest</ns:CustomerTransactionId>
        </ns:TransactionDetail>
        <ns:Version>
            <ns:ServiceId>trck</ns:ServiceId>
            <ns:Major>4</ns:Major>
            <ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate>
            <ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor>
        </ns:Version>
        <ns:Origin>
            <ns:PostalCode>07075</ns:PostalCode>
            <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
        </ns:Origin>
        <ns:Destination>
            <ns:PostalCode>11216</ns:PostalCode>
            <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
        </ns:Destination>
        <ns:ShipDate>2017-07-08</ns:ShipDate>
        <ns:CarrierCode>FDXE</ns:CarrierCode>

    </ns:ServiceAvailabilityRequest>";

$ch = curl_init('http://gateway.fedex.com:443/xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    
var_dump($response);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error you are receiving is transient which means it may be an issue on the FedEx side and will probably resolve itself.

Your request XML looks OK to me.  The only difference I could see was the `packaging` tag.

Here is a working XML request I just took via RocketShipIt (I am the author):

```
<ServiceAvailabilityRequest>
  <WebAuthenticationDetail>
    <UserCredential>
      <Key>...</Key>
      <Password>...</Password>
    </UserCredential>
  </WebAuthenticationDetail>
  <ClientDetail>
    <AccountNumber>...</AccountNumber>
    <MeterNumber>...</MeterNumber>
  </ClientDetail>
  <Version>
    <ServiceId>vacs</ServiceId>
    <Major>4</Major>
    <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
  </Version>
  <Origin>
    <PostalCode>94608</PostalCode>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
  </Origin>
  <Destination>
    <PostalCode>90210</PostalCode>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
  </Destination>
  <ShipDate>2017-07-08</ShipDate>
  <CarrierCode>FDXE</CarrierCode>
  <Packaging>YOUR_PACKAGING</Packaging>
</ServiceAvailabilityRequest>
```

Response:

```
<ServiceAvailabilityReply>
  <HighestSeverity>SUCCESS</HighestSeverity>
  <Notifications>
    <Severity>SUCCESS</Severity>
    <Source>vacs</Source>
    <Code>000</Code>
    <Message>SUCCESS</Message>
    <LocalizedMessage>SUCCESS</LocalizedMessage>
  </Notifications>
  <Version>
    <ServiceId>vacs</ServiceId>
    <Major>4</Major>
    <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
  </Version>
  <Options>
    <Service>FIRST_OVERNIGHT</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-10</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>MON</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>SMOA </DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
  <Options>
    <Service>PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-10</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>MON</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>SMOA </DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
  <Options>
    <Service>STANDARD_OVERNIGHT</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-10</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>MON</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>SMOA </DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
  <Options>
    <Service>FEDEX_2_DAY_AM</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-11</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>TUE</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>SMOA </DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
  <Options>
    <Service>FEDEX_2_DAY</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-11</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>TUE</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>SMOA </DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
  <Options>
    <Service>FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-12</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>WED</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>SMOA </DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
  <Options>
    <Service>FEDEX_FIRST_FREIGHT</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-10</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>MON</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>LAXRT</DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
  <Options>
    <Service>FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-10</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>MON</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>LAXRT</DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
  <Options>
    <Service>FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-11</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>TUE</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>LAXRT</DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
  <Options>
    <Service>FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT</Service>
    <DeliveryDate>2017-07-12</DeliveryDate>
    <DeliveryDay>WED</DeliveryDay>
    <DestinationStationId>LAXRT</DestinationStationId>
    <DestinationAirportId>LAX</DestinationAirportId>
  </Options>
</ServiceAvailabilityReply>
```

Edit: Your ServiceId tag might be related to this error.

Comment: thank you sanbornm. I corrected the serviceId to 'vacs' and that worked like a charm.